# Wordpress not letting me change slug

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress parent page that is named **Test** and children pages that are named

1. Small Test (`small-test`)
2. Medium Test (`medium-test`)
3. Large Test (`large-test`)
4. Mega Test (`mega-test`)

For some reason I cannot change Mega Test's slug to just `mega-test` it keeps rewriting it as `mega-test-2`. When I when to `example.com/mega-test` it redirects me to `example.com/test`. Any Idea what could be causing this rewrite, none of the other URLs are getting changed.

Comment: You have to look into the database - Please have a look into table wp_posts if you didn't change the prefix else yourprfeix_posts table. You can see the slug there already exists. Please modify it to something else and try again from the front-end admin.

Comment: @AnoopMc great call thanks!

Comment: you have a page by that name already, check your trash